# issue with $.ajax in jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In angular js, with `$http()` service we can catch error as

```
return $http(defaultConfig).then(sendResponseData)**.catch(errorCallBack)**;
```

However in jquery, if I do

```
return $.ajax(ajaxConfig).then(sendResponseData)**.catch(errorCallBack)**;
```

then chrome dev tool throws exception.

Comment: `.then(sendResponseData, errorCallBack)` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jqXHR.then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {}, function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
```

**Incorporates the functionality of the .done() and .fail() methods**, allowing (**as of jQuery 1.8**)

```
deferred.then( doneFilter [, failFilter ] [, progressFilter ] )
```

Since the jQuery.Ajax method returns a jqXHR object, which is derived from a Deferred object, we can attach handlers using the .then method as per belo code.

```
$.ajax(config).then(
  function() {
    alert( "$.get succeeded" );
  }, function() {
    alert( "$.get failed!" );
  }
);
```

**Prior to jQuery 1.8,** the arguments could be a function or an array of functions.

For all signatures, the arguments can be null if no callback of that type is desired. Alternatively, use .done(), .fail() or .progress() to set only one type of callback without filtering status or values.

As of jQuery 1.8, the `deferred.then()` method returns a new promise that can filter the status and values of a deferred through a function, replacing the now-deprecated `deferred.pipe()` method. The doneFilter and failFilter functions filter the original deferred's resolved / rejected status and values. The progressFilter function filters any calls to the original deferred's notify or notifyWith methods. These filter functions can return a new value to be passed along to the promise's `.done() or .fail() callbacks`, or they can return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's callbacks. If the filter function used is null, or not specified, the promise will be resolved or rejected with the same values as the original.

Callbacks are executed in the order they were added. Since  deferred.then returns a Promise, other methods of the Promise object can be chained to this one, including additional  `.then()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery [`deffered`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects provied a [`fail`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) method for what many other libraries call `catch`. You can also simply pass a second function to `then`--the second parameter is the fail handler.